# Android - Saving RecyclerView state and items without losing memory on Fragment replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an app which has a lot of `RecyclerView` and `Fragment`. Everytime I go to the next `Fragment` i.e A to B, A's scroll position and values in `RecyclerViewAdapter` saved.

I saved the state onPause like :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getArguments().putParcelable(utilities.BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT, recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
}
```

And resume it onCreateView :

```
Parcelable savedRecyclerLayoutState = getArguments().getParcelable(utilities.BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT);
manager.onRestoreInstanceState(savedRecyclerLayoutState);
recyclerView.setAdapter(
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

The problem is, when I go to B, A is still in memory which leads to very high amount of memory usage till OOM if I were to go A - B - A - B - A - B etc..

The questions are :

1. Am I doing the state saving wrong?
2. Is there a way to save adapter content?
3. How many programmers does it take to change the light bulb?

Answer (score 0):

The RecyclerView is in charge of saving the state automagically. You don't have to do nothing with the state (in many cases). Have a look at this post -> http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en

Your memory issues probably exist because of other reasons. Fragments, as instance of a class, persist in memory after transitions (notice view is destroyed and create again when fragment is visible again). 
If you are saving the List of your items as class variable of the Fragment they will be in memory when you transite from A to B.

It is a good idea for saving memory retrieve the data from a data source (Net or Database) in the OnCreateView method and destroy all the Views (equalize to null) in the onDestroyView

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragmentlayout, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.myrecycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    myDataSource.retrieveData(new DataCallback(){

              public void dataRetrieved(List<Item> items){
                   //This is working on Main Thread
                   recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(items));


              }
     });
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    recyclerView = null; 
    //with this data is freed and GarbashCollector is able to recover memory when the system needs it
}
```

As I said, recyclerView should save its state without any additional code. But It is not working for you, your code is fine.

Comment: So it should save its state without me doing the parcelable thing? And I just realized something while reading your answer, I have every ViewHolder class inside the adapter itself.. Would that make it heavy?

Comment: Yes, android views should save its state without any aditional code. The system preserves for example the typed text in EditTexts when you rotate de screen. In this case the view is destroyed an recreated in the new orientation but your typed text should be there and you did nothing. It is the same case. About the ViewHolders being in the Adapter don't seem to me a problem if you do recyclerView = null on OnDestroyView because the chain of dependencies recycler -> adapter -> ViewHolders is broken and the memory could be freed

Comment: I see.............. So it's the recyclerview then? So the adapter items still persist as long as we don't nullify the Adapter also?

Comment: And, what if the `RecyclerView` is inside a `ViewPager`? Do I have to do `recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.....` again? Or it is automatic in `onCreateView`?

Comment: Yep, if you have a dependency in your fragment to the adapter it is a good idea nullify it too in onDestroy. Please notice that if the system needs memory it is able to destroy fragments or even activities (and its associated fragments) so these good practices allows you to save memory in the normal ongoing of the app. You are making your app "lighter", but the system should be able to manage a "heavy app"

Comment: About recyclers. ViewPager is a mecanism to show fragments inside an horizontal scroll. It have in memory three pages (fragments) at same time with the constructed view, the rest could not be instantiated or with the view destroyed waiting to be showed again to reconstruct it. Each of these fragments (which could use a recyclerView) have a normal lifecycle, just consider follow the indications above.

Comment: Ahh I see, so I should nullify them all.. But I don't know which is dependent on which.. I don't have any variables inside Adapter which is needed by the Fragment as far as I know, is there any other kind of dependency other than variable needed by the Fragment?

Comment: I see that they have normal lifecycle.. But it's weird, I have normal Fragment and a Fragment with FragmentStatePager, the one in normal has its adapter retained even after going forward for about 10-15 Fragments, then go to backstack again.. But in the other case, it's destroyed right when it is offscreen..